# Is there a way to draw multi-page mind map diagrams with PlantUML?

Tags: png, plantuml, mindmapping, mindmap

I have tried using different MindMap diagrams and it looks like this field didn't get enough attention in software development community, so I cannot find enough info on other resources.

Anyway, I use PlantUML to draw Mind Map diagram. The issue is that I draw it from the website, so it gets nested to 6th level and deeper. In PlantUML I can use it either as plain PlantUML or save as PNG file. (It doesn't seem support other formats)

There are several questions but the main is, how can I save/split it as a multi-page?

Sub-questions which also can be answers in my case, how to organise Mind Map to make it readable in PNG? How to keep it on single PNG? Are there other formats supported?

**NOTE:**
Even though this question asks about specific tool (PlantUML), this question touches fundamental question. I struggle to have this peace ready in my software and it is crucial part before the release.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is example of the PNG file I receive after conversion .puml to .png:

[image]

NOTE: The .puml file was too long for plantuml.com to render. The length of the file is 16754 lines.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you tried and what's not working? For example, a large Mind Map that you want to fit on multiple pages? As asked, it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I added some details, after series of experiments I still cannot progress. Maybe you can advice me the way forward with it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen on this large diagram? How do you want the pages to be split? PlantUML can also export to SVG (tools such as Inkscape could possibly print out the large SVG in multiple PDF pages or even other formats). Is your goal to allow users to navigate the mindmap? If so, SVG displays in most browsers, and users can zoom (with Ctrl+ and Ctrl-) and navigate with scroll bars. You could embed the SVG in a web page and possibly allow zooming/scrolling inside it.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Exactly, my goal is to have such a huge diagram, so people can navigate it and find useful info. SVG is something I have thought of BUT. I cannot convert diagram to SVG in IntelliJ IDE (as there is only PNG conversion) and online it doesn't work as it is too large. Can you possibly suggest to convert it to SVG then?

Comment: Try PlantUML using VSCode and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml -- if you use Local rendering (you have to install PlantUML and configure it) you can use large diagrams and produce SVG output. I don't use the IntelliJ plug-in, so I'm not sure if you can also generate SVG with it.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, It was an answer in my case. Can you make your comment to the answer, so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment above, SVG representations of a large Mind Map might be more easily navigated:

> Try PlantUML using VSCode and this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml
> If you use Local rendering (you have to install PlantUML and configure it on your local machine) you can use large diagrams and produce SVG output. I don't use the IntelliJ plug-in, so I'm not sure if you can also generate SVG with it.